# Docker - avoid parent folder name

Tags: docker

I have following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: my_container
    image: postgres:9.6.16-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-xxxx}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-xxxx}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql      
    ports:
      - "31338:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    postgres:
```

This is docker image with empty postgres database. It initializes and works fine, the only thing I don't like is how it looks like in Docker Dashboard:

[image]

There is `db` parent folder which is the name of the folder the docker-compose.yml is located in. I would like to avoid this parent folder.

What should I change in my `docker-compose.yml` to get rid of parent folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to avoid this project-name unless you modify UI of dashboard, however you can change project-name using `-p` option.

By default project-name will use the name of the folder containing your `docker-compose.yml`.

To override with someother name you can use `-p` option like below

```
# docker-compose -p <project_name-goes-here> up -d
```

[**References:**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name)

```
-p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name
                              (default: directory name)
```

> `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` Sets the project name. This value is prepended
> along with the service name to the container on start up. For example,
> if your project name is myapp and it includes two services db and web,
> then Compose starts containers named myapp_db_1 and myapp_web_1
> respectively.
>
> Setting this is optional. If you do not set this, the
> `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` defaults to the basename of the project
> directory. See also the -p command-line option.

Comment: where should I put COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME in my docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy you have put this in your `.env` file, or you can use like `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=someproject docker-compose up -d`